# Integrating modules one solution 4projects

Tags: asp.net

I am trying to integrate 2 modules using Visual web developer

Module1 contains the following: UILayerMOdule1, BLLModule1, DALModule1, webconfig, Site.master

Module2 contains UILayerMOdule2, BLLModule2, DALModule2, webconfig, Site.master

This is how I started.

Create a new project in VisualWeb developer

1. Add project: BLL. I this BLL I added BLLModule1,BLLModule2
2. Project2 DAL: This I added DALModule1,DALModule2
3. Project3: UILayerModule1
4. Project4: UILayerMOdule2

Then put all these under the same namespace.

But it shows an error in Configuration and System.UI. (unable to recognize System.web)

Unable to recongnize System.Configuration

Also, in the UIlayer none of aspx files are shown, Only the aspx.cs and designer are shown

Thanks

Sun

Comment: you trying integrate two web applications or class libraries?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What you can do is

- create new project
- add your web application projects to it (Module1  and module 2) using add existing projects
- Add new class library project and cut and pat DALModule1,DALModule2 , rename the namespace
- add another class library and cut and past BLLModule1,BLLModule2, rename the namespace
- add DAL reference to BLL
- add BLL reference to both UI projects

keep your config files, move only DAL and BLL files to class library projects

Answer (score 0):

Have you added a reference to system.web and system.configuration in the broken project(s)?